# Passing Array to mvc5 action using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass a javascript array where the values are from a multiselect box. However I am getting a null back from the ajax get request when it hits the action.  I have tried to set a breakpoint and it comes back as null.  Here is my action signature

```
 public JsonResult GetMessages(List<string> id, string searchText)
```

and here is my ajax call:

```
$.get("Dashboard/GetMessages", $.param({ "id": JSON.stringify(selectedID), "searchText": InputSearch }, true)
        , function (result) {
        for (var item = 0; item < result.length; item++) {
            var newMessageEntry = "<tr><td>" + result[item] + "</td></tr>"
        }
    })
```

Comment: Show us how you are constructing `selectedID`?

Comment: @ramiramilu  var selectedID = $("select#messages").val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass array data in ajax `POST`, use following code.

Controller Action -

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetMessages(List<string> id, string searchText)
 {
      return Json(true);
 }
```

And your JQuery code should be -

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/Home/GetMessages",
    type:"POST",
    data:JSON.stringify({ id: selectedID, searchText: InputSearch }),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

When you run the application, you should get data like shown below -

[image]

To make `GET` request, use below code.

Controller action -

```
public JsonResult GetMessages(List<string> id, string searchText)
{
     return Json(true);
}
```

And JQuery code should be -

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/Home/GetMessages",
    type:"GET",
    data:{ id: selectedID, searchText: InputSearch },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    // Make sure we have to set Traditional set to true
    traditional: true,
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

And output would be -

[image]

Comment: However this should be a get operation, is it alright to use a POST?

Comment: I would suggest use `POST` to pass more complex data (strongly typed data), and use `GET` for simple parameters and normal querystrings like strings and insensitive data.